# need assistance/recommendation python. 'Acess' Object has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, class, user-interface, authentication

I have 2 files. one is for the login GUI using tkinter and the other is for the login/verification process. In the screenshot the root file runs just fine. When I run the login file the gui box pops up, but when I close it I get an error ---->

```
 '''File "c:/Users/j/Desktop/pyth/login.py", line 20, in <module>
Log.auth()
```

File "c:/Users/j/Desktop/pyth/login.py", line 10, in auth
    if (self.user == Application.capture(self).verify and self.pw == Application.capture(self).verify2):
  File "c:\Users\j\Desktop\pyth\root.py", line 24, in capture
    self.verify=self.username.get()
AttributeError: 'Acess' object has no attribute 'username'''

I understand what the error means, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. Ultimately I'm trying to get the input from the login box once the "LOGIN" button is clicked and see if it matches the assigned user and pw which is what's going on in the login file.

[image: login.py code(error comes from here)]

[image: root.py code (GUI)]

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible example using code snippets instead of screen shots? See [How do I format my code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

It also could be a red herring, but the `Acess` object referenced in the error message may be  misspelled: should be `Access` (with two Cs and two Ss) instead of `Acess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that when you run login.py, the code you wrote in root.py is executed due to the `from root import Application`. This is why the GUI shows up.

Then when you close the GUI, the code `Log = Acess(.., ...) then Log.auth()` is executed and at line 10 of login.py you pass self to the capture method of Application.

And in the capture method, `self.username` is trying to access username of Acess which does not exists and thus crash the code

You could move the code in the root.py file and pass the application to the Acess class and store it in an attribute which will be used in the auth function instead of Application

```
root = tk.tk()
app = Application(master=root)
root.mainloop
Log = Acess("user", "pwd")
Log.auth()
```